# Voice included in omnichannel integration functionality or is it only for messaging platforms?

Tags: voice, smooch

You mention the ability to create an 'omnichannel experience'. I was wondering if this refers to only messaging platforms or if it includes Voice as well.

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Smooch is currently focused on text-based messaging, including messaging platforms like Facebook Messenger and embeddable SDKs for iOS, Android and Web. However, early access integrations exist for the voice assistants Amazon Alexa and Google Assistant.
 You can visit the [integrations directory](https://app.smooch.io/integrations/categories/voice) to request early access to these voice channels